# swift timer in a separate thread

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have the next code:

```
         private var timer: dispatch_source_t?
         private let queue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

         private func startTimer() {
                timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue)
                dispatch_source_set_timer(timer!, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)
                dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer!) {
                    self.process()
                }
                dispatch_resume(timer!)
            }

        private func stopTimer() {
                if timer != nil {
                    dispatch_source_cancel(timer!)
                    timer = nil
                }
            }

        public func callNow() {
            dispatch_async(queue, {self.process()})
        }

           private func process() {
                Log.d(tag, message: "process currentThread=\(NSThread.currentThread())")
            }
```

Why I have `process` method call in two different threads?

```
process currentThread=<NSThread: 0x7f8080e01880>{number = 2, name = (null)} 
  process currentThread=<NSThread: 0x7f8080e03d40>{number = 3, name = (null)} 
  process currentThread=<NSThread: 0x7f8080e03d40>{number = 3, name = (null)} 
  process currentThread=<NSThread: 0x7f8080e03d40>{number = 3, name = (null)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't confuse threads with operations queues. It's is totally normal for tasks from one operation queue to be executed on different threads. From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html):

> Serial queues (also known as private dispatch queues) execute one task at a time in the order in which they are added to the queue. The currently executing task runs on a distinct thread (which can vary from task to task) that is managed by the dispatch queue. Serial queues are often used to synchronize access to a specific resource.